# Clear all Varnish cache from python

Tags: python, flask, varnish

I have a python backend, working as api with Varnish 3.0.7 in front. Every now and then I want to be able to clear varnish cache from my python app - e.i. after some documents have been updated.

I've been trying purge from this tutorial https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html 
but it only purge one object.

I know I can restart varnish but is there any way of deleting all cached objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-varnish

```
from varnish import VarnishManager as varnish_manager
manager = varnish_manager(('localhost:6082',))
manager.run('stop', secret=current_app.config['VARNISH_SECRET'])
manager.run('start', secret=current_app.config['VARNISH_SECRET'])
```

work like a charm...

Answer (score 4):

You can do you it from varnishadmin (varnishadm "ban req.url ~ /"), I'm not sure if there's programmatic way to your requirement.

Update: 
You might take a look on that project https://github.com/justquick/python-varnish (didn't try it myself).